# Why getAttributeName() of ServletContext returns unwanted attributes?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I'm working on a project and having problem with the `Enumeration` reference returned by the `getAttributeNames()` of `ServletContext` class.

Attribute names returned by the `getAttributeNames()` are never added by me, then why did it shows them?

These attributes are:

```
org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager   
org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath   
org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.MergedWebXml    
javax.servlet.context.tempdir   
org.apache.catalina.resources   
org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner    
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache
```

Can anybody tell me how to skip them so that I could retrieve the attributes stored by me?

Comment: Why are you using `getAttributeNames()` in any way? Do you want to debug them? Or are you generating random attribute names for your own attributes so that you can't use just `getAttribute()`? Think about it once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are tomcat attributes used inside their server logic. You dont have to bother about them.

Comment: But what if i want to retrieve attributes stored by me?

Comment: Do getAttribute it sould give you rt?

Answer (score 1):

Every container sets some attributes (depending on the Web server implementing the specification). For instance, Tomcat 5 sets the following context attributes:

1. org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath
2. org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES
3. javax.servlet.context.tempdir
4. org.apache.catalina.resources.

And hence they are returned by the method.

See [This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/177514/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/ServletContext-getAttributeNames) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

These are attributes that the Servlet container (Tomcat in your case) adds and uses internally. Try not to mess with them...

Comment: But what if i want to retrieve attributes stored by me?
How could i skip these server's attributes

Comment: `faisal.abc`. Prefix your own attributes with something and filter accordingly. Or use just one attribute, which is a HashMap, and put all your stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't get rid of the attributes provided and set by your Servlet container.

But you could use the recommended full-qualified nomenclature[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) for attributes to distinguish between "standard" and custom attributes.

For example, instead of `myAppLoggingFolder`, you'd use `org.example.mohammadapp.loggingfolder`.
Then you could simply filter the attributes by their package-like prefix:

```
if( currentAttributeName.startsWith( "org.example.mohammadapp." ) ) {
    // This is one of your custom attributes.
}
```

See for example the `ServletRequest` Javadoc[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)):

> **Attribute names** should follow the same **conventions as package names**. Names beginning with java.*, javax.*, and com.sun.*, are reserved for use by Sun Microsystems.